# Drag and drop tree view asp.net c# without third party control

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I'm looking for ASP.NET TreeView drag and drop functionality without using a third party control. Can anyone guide me with JavaScript code?

Comment: It requires a lot of JS on client side (to capture drag event), so I don't think so.

Comment: Asking for help instead of the possibility!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible out of the box. Of course you could write your own drag & drop functionality, but the effort will be huge and you need to have very good JS and/or jQuery skills to do this.

I would prefer to using a third party JS/jQuery TreeView Control with Drag and Drop capabilities. So you will have less headache with using existing one also less error rate.